# input field displayed out of the box in login form using css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create simple login form using html and css but my input field is displayed below the form what is error..

`````````````````
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="loginForm">
        <div class="heading">
          <h1>Hello heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="formContent">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
````````````````
my csss 
```````````````
    * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: serif;
    height: 100vh;
    }
    .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .loginForm {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px rgb(182, 169, 169);
    }
`````````````````

and this is the link online editor:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-pmvylw?file=styles.css

Answer (score 1):

Try the below changes:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container .loginForm {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px rgb(182, 169, 169);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loginForm">
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>Hello heading</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formContent">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Mainly assigning height as `100vh` on all elements was causing this issue.

Hope that's how you wanted it to look.

Comment: but I assigned it to the parent element then why this not working...

Comment: you used ```*``` and assign height as 100vh. Using ```*``` applied the css on all the elements. Because of this, the heading and the input tag also got the height as ```100vh```.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can declare you width in body and use
`margin: 0 auto;` to get div in center horizontally
than you can apply

`display: flex;`

`align-items: center;`

to center it vertically.

Now your parent element which is body have 100vh and your .container have 40rem height in this situation if you declare your

```
.container .loginForm {
   height:100%; 
}
```

it will take 40rem as a height which is .container(parent) height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: serif;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 35rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  height: 40rem;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
}

.loginForm {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.3rem rgb(182, 169, 169);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="loginForm">
        <div class="heading">
          <h1>Hello heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="formContent">
          <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```